# Combinations of vector with sub-vector length n

Tags: r, vector, combinations

Given a vector, `1:4`, and a  sequence length, 2, I would like to separate the vector into 'sub-vectors', each with a length of 2, and generate a matrix of all possible combinations of these sub-vectors.

Output would look like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    3    4    1    2
```

Another example. With vector `1:8` and sub-vector length of 4, output would look like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
[2,]    5    6    7    8    1    2    3    4
```

With a vector `1:9` and sub-vector length of 3, output would look like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
[2,]    1    2    3    7    8    9    4    5    6
[3,]    4    5    6    1    2    3    7    8    9
[4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9    1    2    3
[5,]    7    8    9    4    5    6    1    2    3
[6,]    7    8    9    1    2    3    4    5    6
```

It's a given that the vector length must be divisible by the sub-vector length.

Comment: the last example pattern is not clear

Comment: For the last example, are these the only combinations?

Comment: Yes. The number of combinations equals the factorial of the vector length/sub-vector length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer the whole question, but it will take a bit longer. This should give you the flavour of the answer.

The package `combinat` has a function called `permn` which gives you the all the permutations of a vector. You want this, but not quite. What you need is the permutations of all the blocks. So in your first example you have two blocks of length two, and in your second example you have three blocks of length three. If we look at the first, and think about ordering the **blocks**:

```
> library(combinat)
> numBlocks = 2
> permn(1:numBlocks)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 1
```

So I hope you can see that the first permutation would take the blocks `b1 = c(1,2)`, and `b2 = c(3,4)` and order them `c(b1,b2)`, and the second would order them `c(b2,b1)`.

Equally if you had three blocks, `b1 = 1:3; b2 = 4:6; b3 = 7:9` then

```
permn(1:3)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 3 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 1 2

[[4]]
[1] 3 2 1

[[5]]
[1] 2 3 1

[[6]]
[1] 2 1 3
```

gives you the ordering of these blocks. The more general solution is figuring out how to move the blocks around, but that isn't too hard.

**Update:** Using my `multicool` package. **Note** co-lexical ordering (coolex) isn't the order you'd come up with by yourself.

```
library(multicool)

combs = function(v, blockLength){
  if(length(v) %% blockLength != 0){
    stop("vector length must be divisible by blockLength")
  }

  numBlocks = length(v) / blockLength
  blockWise = matrix(v, nc = blockLength, byrow = TRUE)

  m = initMC(1:numBlocks)
  Perms = allPerm(m)

  t(apply(Perms, 1, function(p)as.vector(t(blockWise[p,]))))
}
```

```
> combs(1:4, 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    4    1    2
[2,]    1    2    3    4
```

```
> combs(1:9, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    7    8    9    4    5    6    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    3    7    8    9    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9    1    2    3    4    5    6
[4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9    1    2    3
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
[6,]    4    5    6    1    2    3    7    8    9
```